# Propagating information in completablefuture failure

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I'm using completable futures to do a bunch of thing `X`. `X` talks to the internet and can either fail or not fail. When I invoke `X` I pass it a value, let's call it `value`. `X(value)`.

```
    private void X(String value) {

        CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> {
            try {
               Object response = talkToExternalThing(value);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e.getCause());
            }
            return true;
        }).exceptionally(ex -> false);
        futures.add(future);
    }
```

Above is a snippet of what I'm playing with. When it comes down to analyzing the result-set, I can see all values that failed/didn't fail in my test (ie. true or false).

```
Map<Boolean, List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>>> result = futures.stream()
 .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(CompletableFuture::isCompletedExceptionally));
```

My problem is, I want to not only know if it failed or did not fail, but I also want other metadata, such as the `value` that caused the failure. My hope is to potentially have an exception object I can analyze as a result. It's worth noting that the exception *is* a `checked exception (interrupt)`.

Comment: Create a class which can communicate this information, whether the task was successful or not, and then use `handle` to map the result or error to said class.

Comment: When you use `exceptionally(ex -> false)`, the resulting future is never completed exceptionally, as you substituted the exception with a regular value `(false)`. So the subsequent `partitioningBy(CompletableFuture::isCompletedExceptionally)` makes no sense, as `isCompletedExceptionally()` will never return `true`. But when you are interested in the actual exception, why do you replace it with a `boolean` result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my suggestion:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

private void X(String value) {
    CompletableFuture<Pair<Boolean, String>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        try {
            Object response = talkToExternalThing(value);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // un-successfully, with the value
            future.complete(new Pair<>(false, value));
            return;
        }

        // successfully, with the value
        future.complete(new Pair<>(true, value));
    });
    
    futures.add(future);
    
}
```

Comment: Went with similar sorta thing, but just did a wrapper class instead of a tuple. Thanks!

Comment: It’s not clear why this code uses manual completion. The straight-forward `CompletableFuture<Pair<Boolean, String>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()-> { try { talkToExternalThing(value); return new Pair<>(true, value); } catch(InterruptedException e) { return new Pair<>(false, value); } }, executorService);` would do the same.